Specify multiple values for a single attribute in a phpldapadmin template
I'm trying to create a new phpldapadmin template to create new users. The object class I'm using has an attribute called securityRole which can be specified multiple times for a user who has multiple roles.
I want to create a number of templates with differing sets of default securityRoles already set e.g. template 1 has securityRole: 1 and 2 and template 2 has securityRole: 1 and 3.
I can specify a number of empty fields using max
<attribute id="securityRole">
    <display>SecurityRoles</display>
    <order>6</order>
    <page>1</page>
    <max>4</max>
</attribute>

but I can't seem to populate them with the default values
I can do a default value for a single field while leaving empty fields e.g.
<attribute id="securityRole">
    <display>SecurityRoles</display>
    <order>6</order>
    <page>1</page>
    <value>securityRole1</value>
    <max>4</max>
</attribute>

but I can't work out to specify multiple values.
I've tried multiple settings of value with ID
  <value id="securityRole1">securityRole1</value>
  <value id="securityRole2">securityRole2</value>

I've also tried to have multiple attribute blocks for securityRole but that doesn't work either

You may try using a single <value> tag with a comma-separated list of values, e.g. <value>securityRole1,securityRole2</value>

I simplified my samples but the real values are actually DNs which contain commas and no it doesn't split them on commas

Did you try using <default> tags?

I'm not sure how I'm meant to use it. Looking at http://web.archive.org/web/20160810015452/http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Templates it says default: Where  attributes generate a pick list, this will pre-select the default value.
